# Browser specific table column sort icon

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Not for the first time, I'm having a bit of a css issue with IE8.
I have a sortable table which works fine.
It has a direction icon which is displayed as a background to the sorted-by header column and changes depending on whether the column is sorted ascending or descending.
The trouble is, in IE only, the icon doesn't update until the mouse cursor has moved away from the header.

So while the pointer hovers over the column header it stays as the original icon, then when it moves away the correct icon displays.

There is no 'hover' event associated with the headers, but there is css for it.

The css looks like this:

```
.costtable th {
    cursor: pointer;
}
th[order='ascending'] {
    background-image: url(../images/down.png);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
th[order='descending'] {
    background-image: url(../images/up.png);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The part of the script which sets the icon looks like this:

```
$table.find('thead th').removeAttr('order');
$table.find('thead th:nth-child(' + columnNumber + ')').attr('order',ascOrDesc);
```

Before someone points it out, I know there is no `nth-child` css support in IE8, but it does work in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using classes instead of custom attributes!

Seems odd though that it works fine in other browsers.